# How to use Event commands Symfony standalone in my Project?

Tags: symfony-3.4

I have a simple project, and i need implement the Event Symfony 3.4 standalone, however i don't understanding, how to implement it?

Sorry, for my bad english, i'm still learning...

Comment: I used php-DI to pass the required dependencies, and I made the abstractions necessary to build the dependencies that Symfony / Events defines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used php-DI to pass the required dependencies, and I made the abstractions necessary to build the dependencies that Symfony / Events defines.